# Find the smallest ordinal $ \gamma $ that satisfies $ \omega+\gamma=\gamma $

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I know its a really basic question. I'm new to this subject and I'm having some troubles understanding how aritmetic of ordinals works. 
So, a detailed explanation could be really helpful. 
Find the smallest ordinal $ \gamma $ that satisfies

$ \omega+\gamma=\gamma $

Also, I have another basic question. Is it true that for every finite natural number $ n $ it follows that:
$ n\omega=\omega n $

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\omega=2\cdot\omega \neq \omega\cdot 2$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts at all about what such a $\gamma$ might be like? For example, could it be finite?  Could it be that $\gamma=\omega$? Often solving simpler versions of a problem helps you gain inaight that will aid you in solving the full version.

Comment: @MJD I guess it would be $ \omega \cdot \omega $ but I cant really explain why it would be the smallest. Also, can you explain why $ \omega\cdot2\neq2\cdot\omega $

Comment: To show that $\gamma =\omega\cdot \omega$ is the smallest $\gamma$ for which $\omega+\gamma=\gamma$, you'll need to show two things.  First, that $\omega\cdot \omega$ itself has that property, and second that no smaller ordinal does.  As for the $2\cdot\omega\neq\omega\cdot 2$, does your book explain? If not, have you tried Google search for “ordinal multiplication is not commutative”? (I'm not joking, I tried that just now, it referred me to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Multiplication which has an explanation of that very example, although it's quite brief.)

Comment: The reason I'm referring you to other sources instead of explaining it directly is that I'm guessing that almost every source that discusses ordinal multiplication will mention $\omega\cdot2\ne2\cdot \omega$ specifically, probably with some sort of picture.

Answer (score 1):

The least such $\gamma$ is $\omega^2$. For contradiction assume there is a $\gamma<\omega^2$ such that $\omega+\gamma=\gamma$. The sequence $(0,\omega,\omega2,\omega3,\omega4,\ldots)$ has limit $\omega^2$, so $\gamma$ must fall somewhere within those ordinals in terms of size, i.e. there must be some $n\in\mathbb N$ where $\omega n\le \gamma<\omega(1+n)$. With a bit of induction it can be verified that $\omega+\omega n=\omega(1+n)$, and since [ordinal addition is increasing in the right argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Addition), we have $\gamma<\omega(1+n)=\omega+\omega n\le \omega+\gamma$, which contradicts our assumption that $\gamma=\omega+\gamma$.