# Ordinal arithmetic $\alpha = \omega + \alpha$

Tags: arithmetic, ordinals

I am trying to solve the ordinal equation $\alpha = \omega + \alpha$ (with indeterminate $\alpha$). I want to show that $\alpha = \omega + \alpha$ iff $ \alpha \geq {\omega}^2$. The right-to-left implication is pretty easy but I am stuck on the left-to-right implication. I have tried contraposition to show that $\alpha < \omega + \alpha$ but I don't see the argument that would work (the only trivial case is when $\alpha$ is finite of course).

Comment: Hint: ordinals less than $\omega^2$ can be written as $\omega \cdot n + m$ for natural numbers $n, m$.

Comment: Related question (least such $\alpha$): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3702505